# VBNET 2022, Crystal Report CrossTab Layout Crash

Tags: visual-studio

I was watching a video tutorial about the crystal report cross tab and when I imitated what he did there when inputting the summary fields of my database, the vbnet app crashed which is I don't know how it happened, I tried several times, in the summary fields section of the crystal report crosstab and the output is still the same, if anyone knows It would be a big help, thanks!

I tried many times and it is still the same output